# Laptop battery not charging even though Ubuntu says it does.

Tags: battery

I have acquired an Advent 7048 laptop now running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

The battery is recognised and says it is charging but isn't. The laptop runs OK on just the charger. The battery is new, and seems OK. So the problem is either with Ubuntu or the charging circuitry. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Enter the BIOS, disconnect the power cable and try to recalibrate the battery, once you have done this step boot up Ubuntu with the battery and see if it now recognizes it.

Although the battery is new the computer is quite old and it may be having trouble charging the new battery or it isn't fully compatible...

PS: I recommend you to upgrade to the latest version 13.10 because it has a newer kernel and your problem may have been solved already (Use the 32 bit version as the 64 bit version is downloaded by default).